# Does Web Speech API uses the Google Speech API?

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition, google-speech-api, webspeech-api

As per the Web API [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API/Using_the_Web_Speech_API)

SpeechRecognition and SpeechSynthesis supported by Chrome only and it uses the **server-based recognition engine**

Does **Server-based recognition Engine** uses the Google Speech API ?